# Como crear un context para sacar información de la base de datos en las pruebas unitarias de android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, pruebas-unitarias

Estoy haciendo una APP

https://github.com/felipedelosh/LifeRegisterAPP

tiene ya su base de datos funcional con CRUD.

la cosa es que tengo que hacer pruebas unitarias, la base de datos necesita un context para crearse y consultarse.

Por ejemplo un usuario necesita el contexto para realizar operaciones SQL.

https://github.com/felipedelosh/LifeRegisterAPP/blob/main/app/src/main/java/db/DbUser.java

Entonces la pregunta es:

Como hago para crear un context en las pruebas unitarias que me permita que el DbUser le funcionen los metodos de consulta a la base de datos? Que le debo de enviar al DbUser para que funcione?

```
package com.example.liferegisterdiary;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import db.DbUser;
import models.User;

/**
 * Example local unit test, which will execute on the development machine (host).
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
public class DbUserUnitTest{


    
    private DbUser dbUser;

    @Test
    public void registerUser() {
        dbUser = new DbUser(//Aqui nececito el contexto);
        assertEquals(0, dbUser.insertUser("test", "sex", 3333, 8, 99));

    }


}
```

Comment: Existe este sitio milagroso y ancestral, conocido como *Documentación* que contiene la respuesta a todas tus preguntas. En concreto puedes ver la documentación de [ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ApplicationProvider#getApplicationContext()) y hasta la propia documentación de AndroidX te dice que esto se usa para crear un contexto en las pruebas... No habría sido mucho más corto escribir "android doc context test" en google y acceder al (literalmente) segundo enlace que escribir esta pregunta?

Comment: La documentación que encuentro es sobre ser lanzado desde un activity. Además no soy tan experto en android... y busque varios ejemplos y acudo a la comunidad en ayuda.

Comment: @andresfelipeHernandez He actualizado mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas Android X obten el contexto mediante:

> [ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ApplicationProvider#getApplicationContext())  Devuelve el contexto
> de la aplicación para la aplicación bajo prueba.

Lo realizarìas de esta forma:

```
public class DbUserUnitTest{


    
    private DbUser dbUser;

    @Test
    public void registerUser() {
        Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(); //Define el contexto. 
        dbUser = new DbUser(context); 
        assertEquals(0, dbUser.insertUser("test", "sex", 3333, 8, 99));

    }


 }
```

Comment: Hola... despues de tantas vueltas encontre la respuesta:

se crean 2 carpetas (AndroidTest>>Aqui se usa el context);(test>>Aqui solo se usa logica de programación)

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente se crean 2 carpetas:

hay que Buscar una que diga: instrumented test

```
AndroidTest >> Aqui se usa el contexto de la APP (InstrumentedTest)
test >> Aqui solo se usa para logica de programación.
```

https://github.com/felipedelosh/LifeRegisterAPP/blob/main/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/liferegisterdiary/ExampleInstrumentedTest.java